# Arduino copy String to char * and use outside function

Tags: c++, string, arduino, char

I am developing program with ESP32 WIFI microcontroller where I need to scan the available nearby WiFi networks and store them in a list so I can use them later outside the function. I have initially managed to do everything easily using String type variable, but I hear a lot of bad words about using String in Arduino so I am now trying to do everything with char* which I find a little bit more challenging than String.

I have found an article which describes how to convert String to char array:
https://circuits4you.com/2018/03/08/arduino-convert-string-to-character-array/

```
// Define 
String str = "This is my string"; 

// Length (with one extra character for the null terminator)
int str_len = str.length() + 1; 

// Prepare the character array (the buffer) 
char char_array[str_len];

// Copy it over 
str.toCharArray(char_array, str_len);
```

In my code:
I initialise a global variable char array where I want to store my information.

```
char* list_strings[10];
```

Then I call function to scan networks:

```
int scan_wifi_networks(){

  Serial.println("scan start");
    // WiFi.scanNetworks will return the number of networks found
    int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
    Serial.println("scan done");
    if (n == 0) {
        Serial.println("no networks found");
    } else {
        Serial.print(n);
        Serial.println(" networks found");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            
            int str_len = WiFi.SSID(i).length() + 1;  // this is to know the the length of the string +1
            char temp_buffer[str_len]; // create a temporary storage to copy the string to char array
            WiFi.SSID(i).toCharArray(temp_buffer, str_len); // converts string to char array 
            Serial.print("temp buffer is set to=");
            Serial.println(temp_buffer);
            list_strings[i] = temp_buffer;
        }
    }
    Serial.print("list of strings inside scanning function");
    for(int i=0 ; i<=n ; i++){
      Serial.println(list_strings[i]); // prints a lot of garbage??
    }
    return n;
}
```

The function above will scan networks and is suppose to convert the String variable (WiFi.SSID) to char array which I then store into my list:

```
list_strings[i] = temp_buffer;
```

My serial monitor :
[serial monitor image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDpoD.png)

It is able to print out the wifi names properly in for loop, but as soon as it gets out of for loop, it is printing some garbage.

Appreciate any help

**UPDATE1**

I am trying to print the address of temp_buffer:

```
char temp_buffer[str_len]; // create a temporary storage to copy the string to char array
int ptr =  &temp_buffer;
Serial.print("Pointer :" );
Serial.println(ptr);
```

But with no luck. I am getitng a invalid conversion from char* to int error

**UPDATE2**

I have cast my temp_buffer to int and that compiles, however, I do not know if that is correct or not.

```
            char temp_buffer[str_len]; // create a temporary storage to copy the string to char array
            int ptr =  (int)&temp_buffer;
            Serial.print("Pointer :" );
            Serial.println(ptr);
```

The serial monitor:

```
Pointer :1073422080
temp buffer is set to=Telia-33F8A3-Greitas
Pointer :1073422080
temp buffer is set to=HUAWEI-STOLYARCHUK
Pointer :1073422080
temp buffer is set to=Telia-E619A5-Greitas
Pointer :1073422080
temp buffer is set to=Telia-ED7E29-Greitas
Pointer :1073422096
temp buffer is set to=MEZON_1156F3
Pointer :1073422080
temp buffer is set to=Carolyne’s iPhone
Pointer :1073422080
temp buffer is set to=Teo-E6A379-Greitasis
Pointer :1073422096
temp buffer is set to=HH40V_BE2F
Pointer :1073422096
temp buffer is set to=Fishman
Pointer :1073422096
temp buffer is set to=MEZON_9EE8
Pointer :1073422096
temp buffer is set to=4G-Gateway-4981
Pointer :1073422080
temp buffer is set to=HUAWEI-B525-C466
Pointer :1073422096
temp buffer is set to=DGD
Pointer :1073422096
temp buffer is set to=4G-Gateway-D29C
Pointer :1073422096
temp buffer is set to=WIFI 2021
Pointer :1073422080
temp buffer is set to=Telia-E79C95-Greitas
Pointer :1073422080
temp buffer is set to=Telia-E5E1B9-Greitas
Pointer :1073422096
temp buffer is set to=#Telia-1E6E7A
list of strings inside scanning function
```

For some weird reason, the pointer changing from 1073422080 to 1073422096 every now and then

Comment: Where do you want to store the string?

Comment: I want to store the information in the global variable that I create : ```char* list_strings[10]; ```

Comment: that's just an array of pointers though. It only stores pointers to other variables. Which other variable should hold the string?

Comment: Sorry I am not properly understanding what you mean :( Are you asking about the temporary variable that I store the string before I copy it into my array?

Comment: `char* list_strings[10];` can't hold any strings. It can only hold pointers to strings.

Comment: Oh okay. Keep in mind that I am not storing strings, I am storing char arrays. So what would be the correct initialization if I want to store 10 char arrays ? Does it have to be 2 dimensional char array?

Comment: An array of arrays is called a 2-dimensional array, yes.

Comment: Okay that makes it even more complicated then. If I declare my list_strings as ```char list_strings[20][20]={}; ``` which means I am going to have a maximum number of 20 strings and the maximum string length is 20 characters I believe. How do I assign individual char arrays to my 2dimensional array inside for loop?  This wont work anymore ```list_strings[i] = temp_buffer; ```

Comment: correct, `=` does not work with arrays. You can use memcpy or strcpy.

Comment: I see. strcpy works indeed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `char temp_buffer[str_len];`. This allocates memory on the stack (almost certainly the same bit of memory on each iteration of the for loop. I'm surprised this compiled as I would expect to get an error complaining that str_len is not a constant.
In any case you are saving the address of an area of stack that will be available for re-use on each iteration and also after exiting the loop.
It might be informative to print the address of temp_buffer on each iteration.

You could instead allocate the memory on the heap with new() and remember to free it with delete() when finished.

Even better could be to use strings and vectors from the STL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, printing the address of tempo_buffer is not as straightforward on Arduino IDE as I would want it to be. I cannot get it to work. Do you have any ideas how can I print the address of my temp_buffer? I will look into malloc as I do not have experience with it. And also, I have never heard about STL

Comment: I have updated my initial question UPDATE1. I posted some code there. I do not know how to post code in comment.

Comment: The point is that  you are copying the strings to temp_buffer which is a local variable addressing an area on the  stack that will go out of scope at the end of each iteration of the loop. You are overwriting much the same area of stack on each iteration and then saving that address to list_strings[]. By the time you get to look at list_strings [] that bit of stack is probably being used for something else. Even if it hadn't yet been re-used it would only contain the last thing you wrote to it.
I think you need to do some reading on memory management in C/C++

Comment: Ignore reference to malloc(), I should have said new()

Comment: Okay I see, but how is this problem then solved using strcpy instead of = ? How is this different?

Comment: Okay I did some more reading about pointers and memory management. So If I understand correctly, the reason why strcpy works, is because I make a copy of the value inside my temp_buffer and set it to my global variable instead of pointing it to a memory location . That is correct right?

Comment: The main problem is that you are saving the address of a local variable which goes out of scope on every iteration. Once it's out of scope it could contain anything in fact it looks like you overwrite its contents yourself on every iteration. You need to use new/malloc to allocate a buffer to hold the string you want to remember and (assuming you want to avoid memory leaks) use free/delete it when you're finished with it .
As you're using an object oriented language you should know about RAII https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization

Comment: If this helped mark as answer and upvote, thanks.